# Angular ng-select ngModel changes but ng-select not updating

Tags: javascript, angular, data-binding, angular-ngselect

I have an ng-select looking like this:

```
<ng-select
        class="minimal"
        [items]="productGroupTags"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedProductGroup">
        <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
          {{ item.nameI18n | multilanguagePipe }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item">
          {{ item.nameI18n | multilanguagePipe }}
        </ng-template>
      </ng-select>
```

Where productGroupTags is an array of objects and selectedProductGroup is the selected object. It works, when using the ng-select to chose one of the items within productGroupTags, but doesn't work when setting selectedProductGroup from the outside, e.g.:

```
this.selectedProductGroup = this.productGroupTags[0];
```

I'm running angular 11.2.3 and ng-select 6.1

Any idea why this wouldn't work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By default ng-select binds to default label property for display, and keeps whole object as selected value

Please check if you are binding an object into the ngModel, and if it is, do check if it of the right type.

Comment: Hi Nikhil. Thank you for your answer. It is the same type as I'm literally declaring it to be one of the array that represents the items. I'm very confused, as there is an example in the docs: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src/bindings-default-example.component.html which is exactly the same thing I'm doing.

Comment: I've also tried by just assigning as items an array of strings and the ngModel being a string that is set and even with this it does not update the ng-select.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, if you use ng-select inside ngForm you should add the attribute name="yourSelect" :

```
<ng-select
....
name="name2"
.... >
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, turns out I forgot to import the FormsModule. Without this, ngModel is not working, but also it does not throw an error.